# validating using jquery in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="label_left"><label>Name :</label></div>
<div class="text_right"><input type="text" name="usr_name" id="usr_name"  value=""  size="30" /><br  /><br  /></div>

<div class="label_left"><label>Title :</label></div>
<div class="text_right"><input type="text" name="usr_title" id="usr_title"  value=""  size="30" /><br  /><br  /></div>

<div class="label_left"><label>Direct Line :</label></div>
<div class="text_right"><input type="text" name="usr_dline" id="usr_dline"  value=""  size="30" /><br  /><br  /></div>

<div class="label_left"><label>E-Mail :</label></div>
<div class="text_right"><input type="text" name="usr_email" id="usr_email"  value=""  size="30" /><br  /><br  /></div>

<div class="label_left"><label>Organization :</label></div>
<div class="text_right"><input type="text" name="usr_organization" id="usr_organization"  value=""  size="30" /><br  /><br  /></div>
```

I have code as above. I need to check or validate the above using jquery. can anyone help me with some example coding please.thanks

Comment: you simply find it on google. For this you can simply use if else condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(function(){
if($('#usr_name').val()==''){
  alert('Enter Your Name!!!');
  $('#usr_name').focus();
  return false;
}
else if($('#usr_title').val()==''){
  alert('Enter a Title!!!');
  $('#usr_title').focus();
  return false;
}
    ........................
    ........................
    .............
    else{
      return true;
    }
});
</script>
```

This is an example for jquery validation

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have one more doubt to ask you. am aving a button like this  <button id="button1">continue</button> when clicking on this it changes the div content. so before that it has to validate and if validation is done then it has to go to change the div on that button click. can you help me for that please.

Comment: Just put the code for changing the div content inside the else part of the above code

Answer (score 0):

first include jquery after `<head>` tag-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you can do this as follows-

```
<script>

  if($("#usr_name").val()=="")
  {
    alert("please fill username");
  }

</script>
```